# Remove Subdomain from URL in IIS or ASP.net MVC or haproxy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, subdomain, haproxy

Is it possible to remove a subdomain (or basically treat it like www) from the URL?

Example:
**subdomain.domain.com/specific/link/forsubdomain** -> ***domain.com/specific/link/forsubdomain***

and not have it point to the primary domain and return a 404 error,
example:
domain.com/specific/link/forsubdomain -> return a 404 because it only exists in the subdomain.

If it's possible to do something in Haproxy as well Or disguising URLs in ASP.net MVC Route table modifications im open to it.

Not just IIS configuration.

Just wanted to know if it's possible to change the URL as i described and still have it point to the subdomain site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are refering to canonical URLs.

Within IIS you can use [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite), which is a module you can install manually or via the Web Platform Installer (if it's not already installed).

This allows you to create a url rewrite rule which you can configure per site, something along the lines of;

```
<rule name=”Redirect URL to WWW version”
    stopProcessing=”true”>
<match url=”.*” />
<conditions>
    <add input=”{HTTP_HOST}” pattern=”^example.com$” />
</conditions>
<action type=”Redirect” url=”http://www.example.com/{R:0}”
    redirectType=”Permanent” />
</rule>
```

You can add the rules manually to the site's web.config file or use a GUI within the IIS site manager tool.

There's a lot of [reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module) and a number of tutorials available from Microsoft and numerous bloggers.

An [example of a complete web.config](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevelopertips/archive/2008/11/20/tip-25-did-you-know-you-can-have-canonical-urls-and-redirects-with-iis-7-0.aspx) just doing this type of redirect.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="WWW Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^contoso.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.contoso.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Will that also work if the URL was: tomatoes.contoso.com and have it remove "tomatoes" and be contoso.com, but still point to the subdomain?

Comment: Do you mean if someone typed tomatoes.contoso.com you'd still want it to return to www.tomatoes.contoso.com? If so you'd just need to make the rule more specific to include the subdomain in the conditions and the action sections.

Comment: I mean if someone typed **tomatoes.contoso.com**, it would be masked, disguised, or rewritten as **contoso.com**. Yet still pointing to the subdomain and not the primary domain. Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry for delay in replying. Yes, you can use action type of "Rewrite" rather than "Redirect" if you want to retain the display of the original url. Also remove the redirectType if you make that change.